# Why do we say "la cena está preparada" and not "está preparado"?

Tags: traducción

I'm new to Spanish and can't get a handle on this...

> The dinner is prepared.

is translated to:

> La cena esta preparada.

Why isn't this the Spanish equivalent?

> La cena esta preparado.

Comment: Please check [ask] to see how to ask a proper question here, showing what was your research, etc.

Comment: It is because in Spanish nouns have a gender. It is hard to understand for a native English speaker at the very beginning, because there is no such thing in English.

Answer (score 18):

Yes, the correct translation is

> La cena está preparada

Why? Because [cena](http://dle.rae.es/?id=8Bs26eN%7C8Bvhg6D&o=h) is a femenine word, so that you say "la" and "preparada". That is, the participle verb is conjugated also.

With "desayuno", since it is masculine you would say

> El desayuno está preparado

Answer (score 4):

The other answers are right. "Preparada" agrees with "la cena" and "preparado" would not.  I'd like to add one more bit.  Consider the following sentence:

```
He preparado la cena.
```

In this sentence, "preparado" is a past participle,  a component of the perfect tense of the verb.  It does not have to agree with "la cena".

In the original sentence, "preparada" is a predicate adjective, and it has to agree with the noun it qualifies.

Answer (score 1):

Spanish uses two different forms of adjectives for each of the Spanish genders, which are masculin and feminin.

`La cena` is feminin and so it becomes preparada. `El amuerzo` is masculin and would be preparado. A different example would be: `"La casa es mía"` but `"El apartamento es mío."`

There are very few exceptions, where a Word ends on o which is femin or on a and is masculin. Two common ones would be `El idioma` which is "the language" or `La Mano` which is "the hand". Still in this case their respective form of the verb would be used: `"El castellano es el idioma hablado en España."`

Answer (score 1):

For a beginner *está preparad**a*** is easy to be confused with *está preparand**o*** or *ha preparad**o***.

> La cena está *preparad**a***.
>   The dinner is prepared.

In the above sentence *preparada* is an adjective, related to *la cena* and not connected with *está*, and as such it has to match the noun (*la cena*) in the gender (feminine) and grammatical number (singular), so must end with *-a*.

Similarly:

> Las cenas están preparad**as**.
>   El desayuno está preparad**o**.
>   Los desayunos están preparad**os**.

But:

> María está *preparand**o*** la cena.
>   María is preparing the dinner.
>   Juan está *preparand**o*** la cena.
>   Juan is preparing the dinner.

In the above sentence *preparando* is a gerund, and it is a part of the present continuous *está preparando*, which does *not* match the gender and number of the noun (*María*).

> María ha *preparad**o*** la cena.
>   María has prepared the dinner.
>   Juan ha *preparad**o*** la cena.
>   Juan has prepared the dinner.

Similarly, *preparado* is a participle, and it is a part of the present perfect *ha preparado*, which does *not* match the gender and number of the noun.

Answer (score 0):

because cena ending en "A" is femenin and all comming with it must to end in "A" preparada, rica, sabrosa, lista, ... ready... tasety, delicious and done, are sinonimus of this words in spanish when a word ends in O the resst end in o when ends in a the rest ends in a femenin with femenin masculin with masculin